# Apigility - Invalid content type specified

Tags: php, configuration, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I am attempting to post login credentials to an apigility login API:

```
    $response = ClientStatic::post(
        'http://www.example.com/api/login',
        array('email' => 'test@eample.com','password' => 'test'),
        array('Accept' => 'application/json')
    );
```

This returns the error:

> Cannot honor Accept type specified

As far as I can tell, `application/json` has been whitelisted in the configs:

Any ideas?

My Apigility  config:

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Api\\V1\\Rpc\\Login\\Controller' => 'Api\\V1\\Rpc\\Login\\LoginControllerFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'api.rpc.login' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/api/login',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Api\\V1\\Rpc\\Login\\Controller',
                        'action' => 'login',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'zf-versioning' => array(
        'uri' => array(
            0 => 'api.rpc.login',
        ),
    ),
    'zf-rpc' => array(
        'Api\\V1\\Rpc\\Login\\Controller' => array(
            'service_name' => 'Login',
            'http_methods' => array(
                0 => 'POST',
                1 => 'GET',
            ),
            'route_name' => 'api.rpc.login',
        ),
    ),
    'zf-content-negotiation' => array(
        'controllers' => array(
            'Api\\V1\\Rpc\\Login\\Controller' => 'Json',
        ),
        'accept_whitelist' => array(
            'Api\\V1\\Rpc\\Login\\Controller' => array(
                0 => 'application/vnd.api.v1+json',
                1 => 'application/json',
                2 => 'application/*+json',
            ),
        ),
        'content_type_whitelist' => array(
            'Api\\V1\\Rpc\\Login\\Controller' => array(
                0 => 'application/vnd.api.v1+json',
                1 => 'application/json',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'zf-content-validation' => array(
        'Api\\V1\\Rpc\\Login\\Controller' => array(
            'input_filter' => 'Api\\V1\\Rpc\\Login\\Validator',
        ),
    ),
    'input_filter_specs' => array(
        'Api\\V1\\Rpc\\Login\\Validator' => array(
            0 => array(
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'name' => 'Zend\\Validator\\EmailAddress',
                        'options' => array(
                            'useDomainCheck' => true,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'email',
                'description' => 'Email address',
                'error_message' => 'Email address error',
            ),
            1 => array(
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'password',
                'description' => 'Password required',
                'error_message' => 'Password error',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'zf-mvc-auth' => array(
        'authorization' => array(
            'Api\\V1\\Rpc\\Login\\Controller' => array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'Login' => array(
                        'GET' => false,
                        'POST' => false,
                        'PUT' => false,
                        'PATCH' => false,
                        'DELETE' => false,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this case was to run a composer.phar update which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You did setup a `controllers` key in the `zf-content-negotiation` config and point to a `Json` selector. But this selector is not configured. This might be part of your problem. You can also read about this [in the **zfcampus/zf-content-negotiation** documentation](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-content-negotiation#key-selectors). You should add something like:

```
'selectors'   => array(
    'Json' => array(
        'ZF\ContentNegotiation\JsonModel' => array(
            'application/json',
            'application/*+json',
        ),
    ),
),
```

If that doesn't solve your issue please add a comment...

Comment: Thank you - I am using the wysiwig admin to create my api. Would this be controlled from there or do I need to add this manually? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new `selector` over the Admin UI under `[main menu] -> Content Negotiation -> [button] New selector`

[image]

and add/delete/edit selectors there, e.g. adding `ViewModel`s to them.

Content negotioation settings for a service are available in `[side menu] -> Foo API -> Bar service -> Content Negotiation`. There a `Content Negotiation Selector` for the service can be chosen from the lists of content and media types can be edited

[image]

(deleting seems to be buggy and not working -- but anyway it can also be done in the `module.config.php` in the key [`zf-content-negotiation`](https://apigility.org/documentation/modules/zf-content-negotiation)).